# ¿ Como hacer una función puts en C?

Tags: c

¿Cómo se logra hacer una función que imprima en la consola una cadena de caracteres?

Todos los que hemos empezado con C nos preguntamos esto por lo menos una vez, pero en la web solo he conseguido el modo de usar la funciones ya hechas por terceros, como `puts()`. Eso no me responde la pregunta ¿Cómo imprime en la consola una función como `puts` o `printf`?.

Esa es la pregunta que propongo.

Comment: Hola, ¿Cual es el problema que se tiene?, agrega el código que presenta el problema, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Funciones como esa, que interactuan con el hardware, son implementadas llamando a funciones del Sistema Operativo. El código mismo de `puts` probablemente sólo se limite a traspasar datos en uno y otro sentido (pgma y S.O.).

Comment: ¿ Probablemente ?. Interesante. Quieres decir que puts() no es muy depediente de la maquina. @CandidMoe

Comment: Este intento ningun problema que yo sepa. Pero esto es para enseñar. Te pregunto ¿Tu comensando en la programación, te has preguntado como es que las funciones como puts o printf imprime en la pantalla una cadena de caracteres?.@Jorgesys

Comment: @DanielBriceño Esas funciones hacen llamadas al sistema operativo, y el sistema operativo se encarga de lo demás. Mas detalles a partir de eso no te puedo dar, ya que depende de cada implementación. Pero te puedo recomendar [este tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones). Desde cero imprimes algo en pantalla. Talvez asi te hagas una idea

Comment: @DanielBriceño. "probablemente" significa que no he mirado el código fuente de `puts` y por lo tanto, no puedo afirmarlo. Si yo tuviera que implementarlo, buscaría un servicio del S.O. para colocar el string en pantalla.

Answer (score 2):

Esta función es un ejemplo mínimo que implementa la impresión de una cadena en C (terminada con un \0) usando la llamada 0x10 del BIOS. Esta llamada sólo imprime un caracter a la vez.

Está escrita en Assembler y es lo más básico que se puede tener.

```
start:
    mov ah, 0Eh ; Código del servicio de impresión un caracter BIOS
    mov si, text_string ; Registro SI -> apunta al comienzo del string

.repeat:
    mov al, [si] ; Mueve un caracter apuntado por SI al registro AL.
    add si, 1 ; Avanza SI al siguiente caracter.

    cmp al, 0 ; Comparar el caracter con 0 (detectar fin de cadena)

    je done ; Si AL es cero, terminar.

    int 10h ; Generar una interrupción para invocar la rutina de impresión BIOS
    jmp .repeat ; Repetir con el siguiente caracter.

    ; este es el string a imprimir.
    text_string db 'Hello, World!', 0

done:
    ret ; Termino de la función -> retornar.
```

La lógica es recorrer la cadena byte a byte (mundo ASCII -> un byte = un caracter ... con Unicode es mucho más complicado).

En el registro AH se pone la función BIOS que se quiere ejecutar (impresión por consola). En AL se pone el caracter a imprimir; y luego se genera una interrupción 0x10 para invocar al BIOS.

El proceso se repite hasta llegar al final de la cadena.

Nota:

Actualmente todo se escribe en UNICODE, codificado como UTF-8 normalmente. Con UNICODE, cada caracter se representa por uno, dos, o más bytes, lo que complica la impresión.

Comment: Esta función se salta el S.O. y va directo al BIOS de la máquina. Linux se salta por completo el BIOS y accede directamente al hardware una vez que está cargado el kernel. Linux es autosuficiente.

Comment: Interesante solución vas a la parte mas primitiva de la maquina.

Comment: @DanielBriceño. Más primitivo aún es operar directamente con los chips que controlan la comunicación PC <-> Pantalla. Es lo que hace el BIOS

Comment: Mas primitivo significa mas rapido. Lo aprendí a comparar la velocidad de c con C++. Interesante porque me gusta la idea de acceder directamente al chip

Comment: @DanielBriceño. Es bien complicado trabajar directamente con el hardware. Evitalo si puedes.

Comment: ....... Me diste la opción de trabajar con esamblador.... No lo sabia, pense que era un script.

Answer (score 1):

bueno primero hay que aclarar que es un system call para que entiendas
**sys call**

Una llamada al sistema es una llamada a una función que no forma parte de la aplicación pero que está dentro del kernel. El kernel es una capa de software que le proporciona algunas funcionalidades básicas para abstraerle el hardware. A grandes rasgos, el kernel es algo que convierte su hardware en software.

el sys call __write() en linux y **NtWriteFile** en windows son los que escribe en el stdout, printf lo que hace es llamar a esa llamada al sistema

Answer (score -2):

Y que tal si recurrimos al la consola de la maquina, Con ayuda de la función system(); y introducciendo el comando: "echo". Con la cadena de caracteres que deseamos imprimir. Ejemplo:
input
system("echo hola mundo.");
ouput
hola mundo.

Para que funcione nesecitamos incluir el encabesado #include <stdlib.h>, que es la que contiene la función system();.

```C
//solo para windows y linux
#include <stdlib.h>
//Hacemos nuestra propia funciones porque la idea es solo usar <stdlib.h>
int puts(char* a);
int strlen(const char* a){
   int i=-1;
   do{
      i++;
   }while(a[i]!='\0');//sumamos i+1 hasta el fin de la cadena.
   i++;//Marcamos el caracter invisible
return i;
}
//La funcion Main
int main(){
   char a[ ]="Esta es mi función puts.";
    puts(a);
    puts("Espero que les guste.: )");
    if(system("PAUSE")!=0){//Si no es Windows system() retornará 1. Si es windows retornará  0.
       puts("\nInglese una tecla para terminar\n");
       system("read");
    }
return 0; }
int puts(char* a){
  static const char b[]="echo \0";
  long int t=strlen(b)+strlen(a)+1;//Tamaño total que nesecitaremos
  char c[t+1];
  int i;//Almacenará la posición actual del array: c
//concatenamos la cadena en c[] para luego concatenar la cadena c y b 
  for(i=0;i<strlen(b);i++){
      if(b[i]=='\0')
         break;
      else
         c[i]=b[i];
  }
  for(int o=0;o<strlen(a);o++,i++)
      c[i]=a[o];

      
  c[i]='\0';//Si este simple caracter falta hará estrago en la cadena.
return system(c);//Y por ultimo damos la salida por la consola.
}
```

Nota: No se si funciona en otro sistema operativo aparte de linux y windows.